# Creating Irregular ellipses using SQL Spatial 2012 Geometry

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-spatial, ellipse

I have stumbled across a problem in SQL Server 2012 - whereby I need to create different shape ellipses from the following data points:

centre_x | centre_y | max_x | max_y | min_x | min_y

I have tried the create curvepolygon approach but this doesn't work too well, especially if one side of the ellipse is different to the rest, it just seems to create two circles and merges them.

Does anyone have an idea how I can tackle this approach? This is for a project where tree caponies need to be displayed, where the respective shape can be different for each feature.

If there is a way whereby I normal ellipses can be made, this may suffice.

Comment: This isn't enough information to draw an ellipse unless you have a measure of the eccentricity and/or orientation. Multiple ellipses can be generated through the same set of max and min coordinates.